# Google Analytics: Tracking mobile visits on a different top level domain

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, tracking

I have set up tracking for my website with the async snippet, the website is running on `example.com`. Now I want to add Analytics tracking to my (perl-based) mobile website `example.mobi`. I have added the perl-based code and I see the requests to ga.pl coming in:

```
  <img width="1" height="1" src="/cgi-bin/mobile/ga.pl?utmac=MO-12345671F&utmp=%2Fcontact.htm&guid=ON" alt="" />
```

I wanted to track the calls for my mobile website in a specific profile in Analytics. So I have set up a profile with a filter that should include requests from `example.mobi`. However there are no requests coming in on this profile.

What am I doing wrong?